# ld unrecognised emulation mode aarch64linux

Tags: cmake, linker, ld

When running make in CMake, I only get an error that says /usr/bin/ld unrecognised emulation mode aarch64linux.

Im trying to build DualBootPatcher app for Android, this is the error:

`/usr/bin/ld: unrecognised emulation mode: aarch64linux
Supported emulations: elf_x86_64 elf32_x86_64 elf_i386 elf_iamcu elf_l1om elf_k1om i386pep i386pe
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[5]: *** [misc/CMakeFiles/fsck-wrapper.dir/build.make:76: misc/fsck-wrapper] Error 1
make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1786: misc/CMakeFiles/fsck-wrapper.dir/all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [android/CMakeFiles/android-system_arm64-v8a.dir/build.make:111: android/android-system_arm64-v8a-prefix/src/android-system_arm64-v8a-stamp/android-system_arm64-v8a-build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1868: android/CMakeFiles/android-system_arm64-v8a.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2>`

Im running latest Cmake and binutils. Also tried reinstalling binutils.
Im NOT a developers, so it would be nice if you could explain it^^
Does anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 6):

The issue is clear from the fact that the output is coming from `/usr/bin/ld`. This is the system `ld`, rather than the `ld` included with the NDK. You should investigate why this `ld` is being executed instead, for example via `strace`.

For me it turned out to be a file permissions issue - the NDK zip file had extracted without execute permissions, so the toolchain binaries were silently ignored. A few `chmod +x` later and all was well.

Comment: After a while, this become the correct answer. chmod -R +x {NDK directory}, resolve the issue

Comment: not working for me.

Comment: @Moussawi could you tell what is the mentioned NDK dir please ?